# Copy-Item is does not retain filename or extension at destination

Tags: powershell, copy

I am copying an .MSI file to a remote PC.  The `copy-item` is not retaining the filename or extension at the remote destination.  I thought `copy-item` would copy the file as is?

The script:

```
net use Q: \\remotePC\C$\Temp /user:USERID PSWD
copy-item C:\TEMP\installation.msi -Destination Q:\Temp
dir Q:\
net use Q: /delete
```

What the destination directory contains after the copy, a file called "Temp" with no extension.

```
    Directory: Q:\


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---          8/8/2012   3:57 PM   18900480 Temp
```

If I try to literally specify the filename in the destination of the `copy-item` cmd I get the following error:

```
net use Q: \\remotePC\C$\Temp /user:USERID PSWD
copy-item C:\TEMP\installation.msi -Destination Q:\Temp\installation.msi
dir Q:\
net use Q: /delete
```

Error:

```
Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'Q:\Temp\installation.msi'.
At P:\Powershell\CopyInstallFile\copyinstall.ps1:10 char:10
+ copy-item <<<<  C:\TEMP\installation.msi -Destination Q:\Temp\installation.msi
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFound
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.P
   owerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

================================================================
**EDIT** - If I specify the full network path it copies the file correctly.  Apparently the `copy-item` doesn't like to use drives created by `net use`

```
copy-item C:\TEMP\installation.msi \\remotePC\C$\Temp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mapped `Q:` to the c:\Temp folder on the other machine. That means that `Q:\` points to  the temp directory already. Just just copy to `Q:\` instead of `Q:\Temp` and it should work.

```
copy-item C:\TEMP\installation.msi -Destination Q:\
```

Comment: Bingo, I knew I missed something simple.  I was essentially tell it to rename the file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Q:\Temp` doesn't exist. Try creating the the `Temp` folder first, then copy the file.

Comment: It's definitely there.  I think copy-item doesn't like to use drives mapped by `net use` if I specify the full network path it copies correctly.  Weird, but it will do as a work around.